# Can I replace the source image of slices by script?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a Unity2D prefab that uses several slices from a single PNG. (in it sprite renderer, and in its animation clips). If I replace that PNG in the Finder, all slices taken from that PNG are automatically updated, which is great.

But I want to do this by script: just replace the PNG where all slices are taken from, with another PNG. This is so that each of my prefabs instances can all use a different spritesheet PNG source for its slices.

Is this possible in Unity?

Comment: You want to overwrite an asset file on your disc? Or you want to remap an animated sprite renderer to point at a different set of sprite assets? Do you want to do this at edit time, or while the game is playing?

Comment: I want to achieve that effect, without actually overwriting the file. I just want to tell Unity to use a different source file for a specific png. Or perhaps there is a more elegant way to replace all image slices from one image with all new slices?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the sprite of a SpriteRenderer, you can do this:

```
var spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
spriteRenderer.sprite = newBackgroundSprite;
```

The newBackgroundSprite could be added in the inspector (by adding a Sprite to your Script). You can also load resources at runtime; see [Loading Resources at Runtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html).

Comment: That works for a single sprite, but my PNG has several slices taken from it. By replacing that file in the finder, all slices are automatically updated (in my case the sprite also has a few animation clips that use slices from the same source). I was wondering if you could replace a slice source by script.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to put the sprite inside Resources Folder (or make an asset bundle/ addressable) and then you can simply use an array to load all the sliced sprites incorporated with that image(Sprite). The code to load sprites inside an array is.

```
Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Character");
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Unity, you can use the sprite swapping functionality of the [2D Animation package.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@3.0/manual/index.html)

First you create a [Sprite Library Asset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@3.0/manual/SLAsset.html). This lets you define a collection of categories, each describing a category of sprites (like "head", "chest", etc.) and within each logical sprite category you can define several variants, each defined by a label name and the sprite to use.

Then you can add a Sprite Library component to your root game object, referencing this asset, and Sprite Resolver components to the Sprite Renderers you want to swap. Set the category and label on each to point to your original/base sprite for that role.

Now by changing the label field on these components, you can swap to the corresponding sprite for that category.

This makes it possible to swap these sprites at runtime - as characters equip different gear for example. And the sprites don't all have to be from the same PNG or even the same size/shape/layout in the image file (though if using skinned animation, they do need to have identical bones).