# How to update multiple sprites

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a game, with multiple sprites for a player. It includes animations and etc. Player can walk, kick, defend, be hit, etc. Now I developed new sprites to substitute the old ones. One way to change the sprites, would be to move the new files to the same places where the old are, overwriting them. What would be the other possibilities? There is any automatic way to change all sprites in one step?

Comment: why not to drag onto your game object in Unity inspector like all assets (prefabs, sounds etc.) ?

Comment: Did you look at the [Sprite Library and Sprite Resolver components](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/193940/39518) for this purpose?